# Can I replace the WinSxS or Windows folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10, winsxs

I am facing some issues with a corrupt WinSxS folder so I would like to know if I can replace the folder with the WinSxS folder which is in the install.wim in my installation cd/iso. Will it affect windows or will it fix my problem of a corrupted WinSxS folder?
And will my licence still be valid?

Comment: Absolutely not. The files in WinSxs are the exact same files on disk as C:\windows and C:\windows\system32. The files have two names that point to the same area of the hard disk. Settings - Update and Security - Reset PC. or Look at the Settings - Update and Security - Reset PC - Troubleshooter. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions

Comment: So deleting the WinSxS folder will delete the actual files which are in Windows or Windows/system32?

Comment: No it won't. The file is deleted when the last name is deleted. I don't know of anyone who has done it. But Windows Update will never work again as it relies on hard linking the correct version of a file into System32.